# How should be Redux State Anatomy?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working in an complex React App that handles with async calls that brings Deeply Big JavaScript objects. I was wondering what is the better way to create a state to store this objects. The Redux docs says:

> In a more complex app, you're going to want different entities to reference each other. We suggest that you keep your state as normalized as possible, without any nesting. Keep every entity in an object stored with an ID as a key, and use IDs to reference it from other entities, or lists. Think of the app's state as a database. This approach is described in normalizr's documentation in detail. For example, keeping todosById: { id -> todo } and todos: array inside the state would be a better idea in a real app, but we're keeping the example simple.

If I only store the references in my state, where I should store my objects?

Does this question make sense?

What is better for Redux state? A big flattened state? Or a medium not flattened state?

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531563/pattern-for-updating-multiple-parts-of-redux-state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The objects should be stored in redux store as well. The idea is that you can have references to other objects by IDs, instead of nesting complete objects. You can check example on this page: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Answer (score 3):

> If I only store the references in my state, where I should store my objects?

You still store your objects in the state. What that quote is trying to say is, instead of storing a list of todos:

```
{
  todos: [
    {
      id: '1',
      value: 'Pay rent',
      completed: false
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      value: 'Buy food',
      completed: true
    }
  ]
}
```

You could store the todos referenced by id and in the todo list you keep only the reference to it:

```
{
  todosById: {
    1: {
      id: '1',
      value: 'Pay rent',
      completed: false
    },
    2: {
      id: '2',
      value: 'Buy food',
      completed: true
    }
  },
  todos: [1, 2]
}
```

There are a few advantages of this approach. Editing a todo is really easy and you don't need to touch `todos` state. If you later want to reference a todo in another list of todos, you don't need to copy the whole todo object, you simply create a new list with references, for example:

```
allTodos: [1, 2],
urgentTodos: [1]
```

As for your second question:

> What is better for Redux state? A big flattened state? Or a medium not flattened state?

That really depends on your app.